# Hard drive isn't detected during installation of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, storage

I'm trying to install Ubuntu in vmm by Synology, but installer is not detecting hard drive and I can see only loading spinner infinitely on the partition selection page. However, Windows 10 was installed without any problem.

If I boot in ***Try mode*** `fdisk` and `gdisk` can access the partitions.

[image: fdisk]

[image: gdisk]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
First do what our friend @Comar said.
When you arrive at `gparted` do:

1. Open `gparted`:

   1. Delete existing partitions, click the green check button (Apply all operations), then

      > APPLY -> CLOSE
   2. Click on the

      > DEVICE menu -> Create Partition Table.
   3. In (Select new partition table type :) menu choose

      > 'gpt'> APPLY.
2. Do a bootable flash drive using the [Rufus software](https://rufus.ie/).

   1. Add the `.iso` from Ubuntu.
   2. In partition scheme choose GPT.
   3. Click on start.
3. Enable the UEFI option in your BIOS before formatting, this is usually in the motherboard BOOT menu.
4. Boot the operating system installation normally.

Answer (score 0):

In `Try Ubuntu` please open terminal and install qemu-guest-agent from universe repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt install qemu-guest-agent
```

And before running installation try using `gparted` to write new partition table and create an empty partition.

It should be present in live ISO.

```
sudo gparted
```

Comment: I tried it, the result is similar.

Comment: can you please add screenshots from your hard drive setup on vmm synology?

Comment: I tried to install Ubuntu Server 18.04, an error occurs, I think this may be the cause of my problem.
[server install log](https://imgur.com/pUEruAO)

Comment: [vmm setup](https://imgur.com/2OTbzed)